# A union bound on a continuous variable

Tags: poisson-process, point-process

Assume a continuous point process (say Poisson) in [0,t]. Assume that it is given that only three jumps occurred in [0,t], however, their exact time coordinate is unknown. In addition, it is known that 
p(X(t')=1  | a jump occurred in t') < c, and
p(X(t')=1  | a jump did not occurred in t') =0.

Namely, think of X as an event that may occur only at the jump times, and it happens with probability less than  c.

Intuitively, it is clear that since there are only three jumps, the probability that X occurred during this duration,

P(X(tau)=1 for some tau in [0,t]) < 3c

However, it is in fact a union over an uncountable set. 
How to put this formally, in terms of sigma algebra / point processes?
Namely, how to get rid of the jump index t' that doesn't play any role, since only the number of jumps counts?

The key point is here is formally, rather than intuitively.

Comment: What does `a jump occurred in t'` mean? A jump occurred in the _interval_ $(0,t']$? A jump occurred _at_ $t'$?

Comment: The question makes sense if "in t'" means *at* $t'$.

Comment: What do you call the limit of a sum over an arbitrarily large number of arbitrarily small regions?

Comment: Poisson process is a counting process, and I call it a jump whenever the count number increase by one. So, a jump occurred in t' means at t', as Paulius mentioned.

Comment: Re Michael: it depends on the partition details.